# Xcode SwiftUI: mathematical equations / crypto profit calculator

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, calculator, equation

I want to make me an app, where I can calculate the profit that I make out of Crypto-investments. It's written in Xcode SwiftUI.

I don't know how to code the equations. Here is my mathematical equation:

Amount = 10€, Price on purchase date = 12.000€, Price on sale date = 20.000€

1. 60€ / 12.000€ = 0.005 BTC
2. 0.005 BTC * 20.000€ = 100€
3. 100€-60€=40€

How do I transform this into code?

Here is my code:

[image: my code now]

```
 //Gewinnrechner
struct GewinnView: View {
    @State private var anlage: String = ""
    @State private var kauf: String = ""
    @State private var verkauf: String = ""
    @State private var ergebnis: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Anlagebetrag")) {
                    TextField("Anlagebetrag in EUR", text: $anlage)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                        }
          
                Section(header: Text("Kaufkurs in EUR pro Stück")) {
                    TextField("Kaufkurs in EUR", text: $kauf)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                        }

                Section(header: Text("Verkaufskurs in EUR pro Stück")) {
                    TextField("Verkaufskurs in EUR", text: $verkauf)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                        }

                Section(header: Text("Ergebnis")) {
                    Text("\(anlage + kauf)€")
                    }
                
            }
            .navigationTitle("Gewinnrechner")
        }
    }
}
```

There is this test equation in 37: It won't add the "anlage" to the "kauf". It simply writes it down after the first var. E. q.: anlage = 5 and kauf = 7. It wont add it like 5 + 7 = 12. It just makes this: 5 + 7 = 57.

Comment: That’s because you are concatenating strings and not adding numbers. You need to convert your strings to Int or Double depending on your use case and then add them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is about changing String to Double here a working way:

---

```
struct GewinnView: View {
    
    @State private var anlage: String = String()
    @State private var kauf: String = String()
    @State private var verkauf: String = String()
    
    
    @State private var anlageDouble: Double = Double()
    @State private var kaufDouble: Double = Double()
    @State private var ergebnis: Double = Double()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Anlagebetrag")) { TextField("Anlagebetrag in EUR", text: $anlage) }
                
                Section(header: Text("Kaufkurs in EUR pro Stück")) { TextField("Kaufkurs in EUR", text: $kauf) }
                
                Section(header: Text("Verkaufskurs in EUR pro Stück")) { TextField("Verkaufskurs in EUR", text: $verkauf) }
                
                Section(header: Text("Ergebnis")) { Text(ergebnis.description + "€") }
                
            }
            .navigationTitle("Gewinnrechner")
        }
        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
        .onChange(of: anlage) { newValue in
            
            if let unwrappedDouble: Double = Double(newValue) {
                
                anlageDouble = unwrappedDouble
                ergebnis = unwrappedDouble + kaufDouble
                
            }
            
        }
        .onChange(of: kauf) { newValue in
            
            if let unwrappedDouble: Double = Double(newValue) {
                
                kaufDouble = unwrappedDouble
                ergebnis = anlageDouble + unwrappedDouble
                
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```